# Convert directive from Angular1 to Angular2

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular

I am trying to migrate from angular1 to angular2 (on Javascript), how would I write this in Angular2? I am awfully confused

Thank you

```
module.directive('asiPath', function($compile) {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch(
        function(scope) { return scope.$eval(attrs.asiPath); },
        function(value) { asimon.template.load(element, attrs, scope); }
    );
  };
});
```

Comment: where is asimon defined?

Comment: What's its purpose. I don't know Angular1 well.

Comment: Seems incomplete directive in Angular1. `asimon` is not defined. I guess once you load template or deal with template into directive, you have to compile it through `$compile`. You have injected it but not used it anywhere. So seems incomplete directive to me.

Comment: asimon is defined as a global variable, you're right $compile is extra there